# Can I use NSURLSession (in iOS) to upload Azure Blob in to a container?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, nsurlsession

I am working on an app where I want to upload photos from iPhone photos to Azure Storage. The upload will be triggered in foreground, but I want the upload to continue in background, even if the app is suspended. I am wondering if I can use NSURLSession for this purpose?

Comment: Per my understanding, you could use upload tasks provided by the NSURLSession class to achieve your purpose, and you may need to follow [Put Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob) to construct the related  request headers.

Comment: Did you find a way to achieve this? I have the similar requirement.

Comment: you can use AZSClient library for that purpose, it uses NSURLSession. For my case i used background task to keep it running for longer and then used location api to get callbacks to 'wakeup' up the app